# Files Lost during move in cPanels File Manager

Tags: cpanel

I had a task that required me to move files from a subdomain to the public_html directory on my cPanel. To move them I simply selected the files and directories I wanted from the subdomain, clicked move and entered the destination path.

Once the move process had completed, only some of the files and folders were in the new location (public_html). The files that didn't move to the new location no longer seem to exist.

Has anyone encountered this problem before and is there any way to recover the lost files (they aren't in the trash)?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to connect to your server with other FTP client like FileZilla or something similar to see if the files are still missing. It seems like UI glitch. cPanel represents only an user interface and is not able to delete the files.